# Unable to insert nested json into cassandra

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I am new in Cassandra. I have created one sample table. Right now facing problem during insert.

created employee like below :

```
create table employee(
  emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  department text,
  skillswithrank map
);
```

Written query :

```
INSERT INTO company.employee(emp_id,first_name,last_name,department,skillswithrank )
 VALUES (1,'sam', 'watson', 'IT', [{"nodejs":4},{"angularjs":4},{"expressjs":4}]);
```

I am stuck at this point.

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.4.4 version

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to insert a list of maps, instead of map, so your insert doesn't match to table definition.  Plus you're using incorrect syntax for strings in the map.

you need to write insert as:

```
INSERT INTO company.employee(emp_id,first_name,last_name,department,skillswithrank )
  VALUES (1,'sam', 'watson', 'IT', {'nodejs':4, 'angularjs':4, 'expressjs':4]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. company.employee is a demo table. I have another table, In that, I am trying to insert nested JSON. But I am unable to Insert.

Comment: please share the real table structure, what you want to insert, and what error you get - otherwise it's impossible to answer the question

Comment: Please refer below structure : 
 create table company.executionInput (
  ExecutionInputID bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  ExecutionLogID bigint,
  Acc_Type text,
  Email_Valid int,
  Country text,
  Customer_Accounts map<text,text>,
  CurrentOrder_List map<text,text>
 );

Comment: I am getting error like : Invalid list literal for customer_accounts of type map<text, text>

Comment: I wrote in my answer that you have map declared in the table, but you're inserting a list of maps instead...

Comment: Can we Insert list of maps in Cassandra table? If Yes then can you please suggest me?